# How do I unmarshall java.nio.Path using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, nio

I have been trying to unmarshall some xml using JAXB but I keep getting the error:

`java.nio.file.Path is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.`

Is there any way to tell JAXB how to build paths from strings?

My class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Project extends OutputConfiguration {
    private Path sourceDir;
    private Path buildDir;
    private String name;

    /**
     * Get the root directory of the sources.
     * This will be used as the working directory for the build.
     *
     * @return the path
     */
    public Path getSourceDir() {
        return sourceDir;
    }

    /**
     * Get the root directory of the sources.
     *
     * @param sourceDir the path
     */
    @XmlElement
    public void setSourceDir(Path sourceDir) {
        this.sourceDir = sourceDir;
    }

    /**
     * Get the build directory.
     * This is the directory where all outputs will be placed.
     *
     * @return the path
     */
    public Path getBuildDir() {
        return buildDir;
    }

    /**
     * Set the build directory.
     *
     * @param buildDir this is the directory where all outputs will be placed.
     */
    @XmlElement
    public void setBuildDir(Path buildDir) {
        this.buildDir = buildDir;
    }

    /**
     * Get the friendly name of the project.
     *
     * @return the name of the project
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Set the friendly name of the project.
     *
     * @param name the name
     */
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I have created an ObjectFactory class that calls the default constructor and sets some defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is XmlAdapter and @XmlJavaTypeAdapter.

You have to create a class that extends XmlAdapter, let's say XmlPathAdapter, implements the abstract methods then you will need to annotate your Path getters or fields with @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(XmlPathAdapter.class).

Look at the XmlAdapter documentation for an example an further details :
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html

Comment: This doesn't work because `java.nio.file.Path is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.`, and the JDK does not provide and public implementations of Path.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this, both of which are required for this thing to work:

---

You cannot create a `XmlAdapter<String, Path>` due to the `java.nio.file.Path is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.` error. Therefore you must use a `XmlAdapter<String, Object>`, which works since `Object` is a superclass of `Path`:

```
public class NioPathAdaptor extends XmlAdapter<String, Object> {
    public String marshal(Object v) {
        if (!(v instanceof Path)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(...);
        ...
```

---

You then must use a very specific `@XmlElement` and `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` on your attribute:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(NioPathAdaptor.class)
@XmlElement(type = Object.class)
private Path sourceDir;
```

The `type = Object.class` tells JAXB to serialize this as-if it was an `Object`, and the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` says to use that specific `Object` adapter for that specific field, instead of another, more generic adapter.